# Drupal 8.2.2 kint output in template not working

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

We are trying to use the kint() or drump() debugging functions inside twig templates in Drupal 8 but both does not seem to be working even though we have tried all the approces to get them working available online.

I have renamed my default.services.yml file to **services.yml** and set **twig.config** *debug, auto reload and cache* to **true**, yet I can't get any output out from those functions; however, it does not fail with a non-existent function error either.

When I try to use the dsm() function in my controllers or other files outside twig templates, it works as expected.

Any idea where the problem might be?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled the Devel Kint module along with the Devel module?

Comment: Of course I did.

Comment: Do you have the Twig extension installed and enabled in your apache? Should be able to get the Twig version from phpinfo()